# Eclipse editor background color per project

Tags: eclipse

Is there a setting or plugin to have a different background on a per-project-basis in Eclipse?

I sometimes have 3-5 projects open at the same time, for example a server, a webclient and a native client with similar filenames and I always have to look twice if I am in the right project.

If there were different background colors per project, I could navigate so much better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set background color at the project level in Eclipse. You can confirm this yourself by examining the available options in **Properties** for any project.

However, there is an alternative approach:

- Open **Package Explorer** and click the **Link with Editor** icon:

[image: link1]

- Note that in the screen shot above the file **App1.java** is selected in the editor, and its node is also highlighted in **Package Explorer**.
- Now select a different file in the editor. Note that the node for the selected file now automatically becomes the highlighted node in **Package Explorer**.

[image: link2]

I realize that you were asking for something else, but since that is not possible this is an alternative that might be better than nothing to help with navigation.

[This is the Eclipse documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-18.htm) for **Link with Editor**.

Comment: Thank you for alternative approach. I am already using the **Link with Editor** feature, but having different backgrounds would by way better (for me).

Comment: OK. The only other approach that comes to mind is to have different background colors for different workspaces, and then run multiple instances of Eclipse concurrently. But I'm guessing that you specifically want/need your projects to be in the same workspace, in which case that isn't a realistic option. I'm pretty sure that if what you want is possible someone would have a created a plugin for it by now, but unfortunately I don't see one; Eclipse just doesn't offer any color customization at the project level (which seems a bit strange since you can format code at the project level).

Comment: Thank you for your ideas, I really appreciate it! But it is not really what I am looking for. Maybe some day someone creates a plug-in :-)